# Plotting a 2D polar mesh with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that is computed on a 2D polar mesh:

```
# The mesh created is in two dimensions: r and theta.
# Mesh steps in theta are regular, while mesh steps in r are more refined
# close to the origin
nb.theta <- 50
theta.max <- 130
theta <- seq(0, theta.max, length.out = nb.theta)

nb.r <- 80
# r goes from r0 to rMax
q0 <- 1.1
z <- seq(1, nb.r)
rMax <- 30
r0 <- rMax / (q0 ^ nb.r - 1)
r <- r0 * (q0 ^ z - 1)

# Now let's add some data
mesh <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(r = r, theta = theta))
mesh$value <- mesh$r * mesh$theta / theta.max
```

Now, I want to plot the mesh in R (preferably with ggplot2). I tried:

```
ggplot(mesh, aes(r, theta, color = value)) + geom_point() + coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

But the result is far from satisfactory:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to have cells filled and not just points. I also would like the plot not to be a full circle: I only have data from 0 to 130 degrees.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `geom_tile` rather than `geom_point` so that we fill the mesh. We need to calculate the width of each window. Here I've just set it to r/10 which is approximately correct. You will be able to calculate it exactly.

Adding `ylim` ensures that only part of the circle is filled.

```
mesh <- expand.grid(r = r, theta = theta)
mesh$value <- mesh$r * mesh$theta / theta.max
mesh$width <- mesh$r/10


ggplot(mesh, aes(r, theta, fill = value, width = width)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
    ylim(0, 360)
```

NB `expand.grid` returns a data.frame, so we don't need to convert it.

[image]

Comment: That's nice. But the plot is still half empty. Would it be possible to cut the plot, say with a line going from 0 to 180 degrees?

Comment: Perhaps - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398350/how-to-show-only-part-of-the-plot-area-of-polar-ggplot-with-facet/22418817#22418817

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's an ugly hack tough.

Comment: Can we just stay in Cartesian coordinates and change the shape of the tiles ?

Answer (score 2):

This should solve the circle issue:

```
ggplot(mesh, aes(r, theta, color = value)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,360))
```