# Rose diagram for migration data

Tags: r, ggplot2, rose-plot

I am trying to create a rose diagram showing average trajectory angle and distance for each subset of cells. I want the angle around the rose diagram to be the trajectory angle and the length of the bar in the diagram to be the total displacement.

Here is a test data set of the mean angle and displacement per group.

```
testsum<-data.frame(Group=c(1,2,3),
                angle=c(0.78,1.04,2.094),
                displacement=c(1.5,2,1))
```

When I try to plot this in a circular method, my chart looks very wrong.

```
p1<-ggplot(testsum, aes(x=angle,y=displacement))+
  coord_polar(theta="x",start=0)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(color=Group,fill=Group),width=.01)+    
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,60))
```

It gives me this graph for output.

[image]

When based on what the data says, it should look more like this (drawing of intended output).
[image]

It seems to be placing the angles incorrectly? Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the expected diagram group 3 appears twice. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. I updated my diagram.

Comment: Love the diagram edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
testsum$angle_b=180*testsum$angle/pi
#
ggplot(testsum, aes(x=angle_b,y=displacement))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(color=Group,fill=Group),width=1) +    
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,10), limits=c(0,360)) + coord_polar(direction=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Although MLavoie "beat me" by 20 minutes, I think some readibility can be added by using `NISTunits` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(NISTunits)

testsum <- data.frame(
  Group = c(1, 2, 3),
  angle = c(0.78, 1.04, 2.094),
  displacement = c(1.5, 2, 1)
)

testsum$angle = NISTradianTOdeg(testsum$angle)

ggplot(testsum, aes(x = angle, y = displacement)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = NISTdegTOradian(-90), direction = 1) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           aes(color = Group, fill = Group),
           width = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, 10), limits = c(0, 360))
```

Result:

[image]

To clip the bottom half check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418817/4272484)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use windRose function from open air package

```
library(openair)
    testsum<-data.frame(Group=c(1,2,3),angle=c(0.78,1.04,2.094),displacement=c(1.5,2,1))
    testsum$angle=180*testsum$angle/pi
windRose(testsum,ws="displacement",wd="angle",breaks=c(0.5,1,1.5,2),paddle=F,key.header = "My Rose",angle=10, 
     statistic="prop.mean",key.footer = "Displacement")
```

[image]